# What's the optimal strategy of this dice game?

Tags: dice, dynamic-programming

I'm working on dynamic programming problems this week. The following is a dice game. I'm trying to find the optimal strategy using dynamic programming.

The game's description :

The player rolls two dice.

- If the sum of the numbers shown by the two dice are equal to the precedent sum (precedent round) then the player will loose all his reward.
- Otherwise the player will add the sum given ($2+3$ for example) to the cumulative rewards he has.

I started modeling the problem. The state of the system is as follow: 
I chose one random number (400 for example) that may be the maximum reward for $N$ rounds game. The state is $V_k(S,D)$ where $S$ is the cumulative sum and $D$ is the sum of the two numbers shown on the two dice.

If we suppose that the numbers of rounds is finite, what will be the optimal strategy in a simple form?

In the case of infinite game what's the mean of the reward?

Thank you in advance guys :)

Comment: If you get the running total over 12, are you safe?

Comment: I'd suggest to use "sum" for the sum of the two dice and "total" for the running total of the reward throughout. I suspect that the answer to @Ross' question above is that "the precedent sum (precedent round)" refers to the sum of the two dice in the preceding round, not the running total of the preceding round? When you say that the player will lose their reward, does that end the game and the value is $0$, or can the player start accumulating rewards again? I presume the former, since the latter would lead to the game value being infinite.

Comment: The player should be able to decide when to stop but he can continue if he sees that he can get a better reward. Precedent round refers to the sum of the two dice in the preceding round.

Comment: @Samatix: Do I understand correctly that you're saying that the player can start accumulating rewards again when they lose the reward? (That's what I'd asked about.) Are you aware that in that case the game is infinite and the player can obtain an arbitrarily high reward? My answer assumes that the game ends when the sum is repeated and the reward is lost.

Comment: @Joriki : Thank you so much for you quick answer. Yes that's what I said. But the optimal strategy will tell you when to stop rolling the dice even if the mean of the rewards in the infinite case is equal to infinity. Do you have a proof that the mean at the infinity is infinite ? The goal is to find the optimal strategy. For example the answer bellow says that if you have like a reward of 123 stop. That's what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: I don't understand the question too well, as worded. Frankly I dont see any room for strategy in this game. The player is left entirely in the hands of random chance. There is no betting, no action, no choice but a continuous reiterative process of random dice rolls.  This is tantamount to asking for a strategy to the card game of War.

Comment: @Cogito: You're right; I assumed that it was meant to be implied that the player can dedide anytime to stop and take the accumulated reward.

Comment: @Samatix: What you say about the infinite game makes no sense to me. How could an optimal strategy tell you to stop rolling if the expected value is infinite? And it's not just that, as you say, the expected value is infinite; the player can get an arbitrarily high award with probability $1$. This is simply because there's a finite probability of achieving that reward in finite time, and if you try infinitely often, the probability of succeeding once goes to $1$.

Comment: It seems to me, then, that the player should keep playing, indefinitely if needed, until he wins sufficiently many consecutive games such that winning another is statistically improbable.  Find yourself a confidence interval of your choice where the expected number of games is less than your boredom threshold.

Comment: @Cogito: "until he wins sufficiently many consecutive games such that winning another is statistically improbable": That seems to indicate a fundamental misunderstanding of probabilities -- how likely it is to win another game doesn't depend on how many have been won so far.

Comment: @joriki. I recognize that. No misunderstanding here. But as I stated at the very beginning, Im not sure what is meant by the question. Do you know more about the intent behind this question than I do?

Comment: Im having people in another probability question insist to me that past probabilities do effect future probabilities and Ive been arguing the point with them for a couple of hours now. HA.

Comment: @Cogito: Then I don't understand what you mean by "until he wins sufficiently many consecutive games such that winning another is statistically improbable". To answer your question: As I've been saying, there are two interpretations of the question; if the player can restart after losing everything, they can trivially get as much as they want; if they can't restart and the game ends with the loss, then my answer below gives the game value and the optimal strategy. As far as I can tell what you wrote fits with neither of those two interpretations.

Comment: I have deleted an inappropriate comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a Sage session that calculates the expected value and the optimal strategy:

```
sage: @CachedFunction
sage: def f(s,d):
...       if (s > 500):
...           return s    
...       exp = 0
...       for i in range (2,13):
...           if i != d:
...               p = (6 - abs (7 - i)) / 36
...               exp = exp + p * f (s + i,i)
...       return max (s,exp)    
sage: f (0,0)
5102856371420701910406444770125748115514599426793322429508600411301424025583837413991140684712401545/200826102839256313932089349950528975334638448502151718250240746889056739809428118955117185815543808
sage: _.n ()
25.4093282659829
sage: for i in range (2,13):
...       for s in range (0,500):
...           if f(s,i) == s:
...               print "If you rolled",i,", stop if you have at least",s
...               break
If you rolled 2 , stop if you have at least 250
If you rolled 3 , stop if you have at least 127
If you rolled 4 , stop if you have at least 86
If you rolled 5 , stop if you have at least 66
If you rolled 6 , stop if you have at least 54
If you rolled 7 , stop if you have at least 46
If you rolled 8 , stop if you have at least 53
If you rolled 9 , stop if you have at least 63
If you rolled 10 , stop if you have at least 81
If you rolled 11 , stop if you have at least 119
If you rolled 12 , stop if you have at least 241
```

Thus the game's value is about $25.4$, and the reward at which to stop depends strongly on the probability of repeating the last roll, and is also slightly higher for the lower of two equiprobable sums (e.g. $2$ and $12$), as might be expected.

Comment: This really a pertinent answer. Could you please give me more details. What does the function f refers to ? is it the payoff ?

Comment: @Samatix: Yes, $f$ calculates the payoff for the arguments `s` and `d`, which correpsond to your variables $S$ and $D$. It does so by comparing the expected value if you roll again to the sum you could keep if you stop. The results are automatically cached due to the decorator `@CachedFunction`.

Comment: I still have one question if I don't bother you. How did you get the 25.4 (the game value).

Comment: @Samatix: I called `f (0,0)`, which yields a huge fraction, and then called `n ()` on that to get its decimal representation. (I guess the answer to your first question should have been that `f` calculates the *expected* payoff, so `f (0,0)` is the expected payoff at the beginning of the game, i.e. the game value.)

Answer (score 0):

The Game Strategy: stop rolling and keep the current reward if and only if the next rolling will not increase the reward statistically.

The Game Value: expectation of reward of this game based on the above game strategy.

I implemented a C++ implementation as follows,
 http://cpluspluslearning-petert.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/dynamic-programming-game-value-of.html.

Game value calculated on this example is: 22.224974509843324.